# How much should I be in conversation with department faculty after acceptance?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I was accepted to a Ph.D. program in the States after being waitlisted. Throughout the process, I've have little to no direct communication with current faculty besides the thank-you emails I sent post-interview. This includes with my intended POI, who wasn't at my interview and hasn't responded to any of my requests to chat (I've since learned that they are probably leaving the University, which is also an issue that I've tried to bring up with other faculty). I would be more than happy with a 30-minute chat via Zoom so that I can at least get a sense of these faculty members, and find it very weird that other current students also didn't meet with faculty after being accepted.

I would really like to consider enrolling in the program, but the radio silence from every faculty member I've reached out to for weeks has basically scared me off. I'm an older learner, and I'm also eager to ask more brass tacks questions rather than just the general marketing jargon that some University reps have shared.

My experience with other programs has been extremely different, with phone messages and immediate invitations from them to meet via Zoom. I didn't expect this situation and feel very disappointed about the circumstances. I also don't feel comfortable committing to a program whose faculty might not have the time to engage with their students?

Comment: Will you be entering with a bachelors or a masters?

Comment: A bachelors degree.

Comment: This seems normal. I wouldn't worry too much about the post-admission silence. There are so many aspects that could change at or after you join, and its understandable that advisors would want to discuss the brass tracks after you physically join the department.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal for US doctoral admissions, especially if you will have only a bachelors on entry. The first task in most fields is to take advanced coursework that gives you a broad, advanced, view of your field and enables you to pass comprehensive exams. It is rare, but not unheard of, to start research immediately or to need a dissertation advisor for a couple of years.

This gives you and them a chance to look one another over.

Since this is the norm, faculty will wait until you have a few courses before wanting to talk seriously with you. It also gives you more information at the time it becomes necessary to choose. Relax.

Until you pass comps, all is tentative and conditional.

Comment: The bigger issue at this point is that my intended POI is leaving, and I'm not sure if anyone else has the ability to support my (regionally-based) research. I would like some dialogue about this since I have other offers.